# Определить класс объекта

Tags: c++, qt5

Есть ли стандартная ф-ция определения класса объекта?

```
class A { };
class B: public A { };

int main()
{
    B b;
    A *pa = &b;
    // false, а нужно что-то что выдает true
    cout << (typeid(*pa).hash_code() == typeid(B).hash_code());
    // true, а нужно что-то что выдает false
    cout << (typeid(*pa).hash_code() == typeid(A).hash_code());
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первый вариант легко реализовать (если включить RTTI и если класс полиморфный):

```
cout << (nullptr != dynamic_cast<B *>(pa));
```

Если класс не полиморфный то после приведения к базовому типу узнать оригинальный тип на основе RTTI нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

`decltype()` - годится не только для классов, но и вообще для типов данных.